# What's the point of the :ok init argument in Elixir's GenServer example?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

In [Elixir's intro to GenServer](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html), the client API starts the server with an `:ok` argument

```
def start_link(opts \\ []) do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, opts)
end
```

And the server's `init` function requires its argument to be `:ok`

```
def init(:ok) do
  {:ok, HashDict.new}
end
```

What's the point of passing and verifying `:ok`? Would it be any different if we were to omit this and instead write something like

```
def start_link(opts \\ []) do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, opts)
end

def init(_) do
  {:ok, HashDict.new}
end
```

?

Comment: I don't think it matters as the tests still pass if you use `:ok` or `nil`. Passing `:ok` and having `init(:ok)` might just be an added check via pattern matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its important to remember here that the second argument passed to `start_link` will become the argument of the `init` function. Because this is a simple example they have used atom like :ok and can be replaced by nil. You need to pass the second argument be it nil.

So answering your question, in this example `:ok` can be replaced by `nil`. I think they used `:ok` since there must be an argument and `:ok` looks like a good choice(just a preference)

In other situations you have to make use of this information to fetch some important data or for pattern matching

```
defmodule ServerDrop do
   use GenServer

defmodule State do
    defstruct count: 0
end

def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,:ok,[{:name,__MODULE__}])
    #GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,[],[{:name,__MODULE__}])
end

def init(:ok) do
    {:ok,%State{count: 10}}
end

def init([]) do
    {:ok,%State{}}
end

#Code left out for brevity
```

In other situations you many need to get some data

```
def init(stash_pid) do
    current_number = Stash.get_value stash_pid
    {:ok,{current_number,stash_pid}}
end
```